# creating regular data times every 0.01 s from irregular data times

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I doubt that my program gives me false result.

I have an irregular time series data: (time (h:m:s:ms), X-acceleration, Y-acceleration, Z-acceleration)in hexadecimal

Portion of my log file

```
7:43:08.437 > ATT_HandleValueNotification: status=0 h=45 n=3 07 C7 17
17:43:08.477 > ATT_HandleValueNotification: status=0 h=45 n=3 07 C7 17
17:43:08.437 > ATT_HandleValueNotification: status=0 h=45 n=3 07 C7 17
17:43:08.477 > ATT_HandleValueNotification: status=0 h=45 n=3 07 C7 17
17:43:08.497 > ATT_HandleValueNotification: status=0 h=45 n=3 07 C7 17
17:43:08.516 > ATT_HandleValueNotification: status=0 h=45 n=3 07 C7 17
17:43:08.537 > ATT_HandleValueNotification: status=0 h=45 n=3 09 C7 17
```

The first column is for a Time and the three last columns are for acceleration's data (x,y,z).

My goal here is to interpolate irregular Time series to regular time series and i would like to obtain acceleration's data  every 0.01 seconds.

My code matlab :

```
s=data(:,3)+data(:,4)/1000; % convert to seconds+fractions



t = datenum(2014,07,18,data(:,1),data(:,2),s)*86400;

t = t - t(1);

sample = interp1(t,res(:,1:3), 0:0.01:t(end)); % i fixed a time to 100ms to obtain estimated data in this time
```

After converting acceleration's data from hexadecimal to acceleration's g  , i obtain this table

```
0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,140625000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000
```

And this a portion of a table sample after applying interp1 function :

```
0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,110866306584362   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,125746056832695   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,140624576267240   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,132812426778048   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,125000277288855   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,117188127799663   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375978310470   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000

0,109375000000000   -0,890625000000000  0,359375000000000
```

end
i think that i have a duplicate values

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: My res is array contains a 342 rows but after executing interp1 function , it gives me 23849 rows with duplicates rows as follow, is this normal? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your query points also cover your sample points. If you want to avoid producing duplicates, just remove the sample points from your query point set, e.g.:

```
% prepare your data:
t = datenum(2014,07,18,data(:,1),data(:,2),s)*86400;
samplepoints = t - t(1);
querypoints = 0:0.01:t(end);

% remove sample points from query points:
newQuerypoints = setdiff(querypoints,samplepoints);

% obtain values as usual:
queryvalues = interp1(samplepoints, samplevalues, newQuerypoints);
```